# Como guardar valores num vetor usando herança/polimorfismo?

Tags: java

Estou iniciando na linguagem Java e me deparei um problema. É o seguinte: Tenho 1 classe que chama Veiculo, nela tem o atributo marca(string) e tem 3 classes que a herdam, no caso são: Carro(qtdPortas int), Moto(qtdCilindradas int), Barco(potMotor int) e terei um vetor[] para armazenar os veiculos inseridos, o meu problema é o seguinte, como faço pra inserir no vetor[] um objeto do tipo Carro, ou Moto, ou Barco, especificamente? Eu tinha pensado no seguinte código, mas ele serve apenas pra inserir valores normais, quando não existe herança, como ficaria o código pra inserir num vetor quando existe herança?

```
public void insereVeiculo(Veiculo veiculo)
    {
        int contador = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.vetVeiculo.length; i++) 
        {
            if(this.vetVeiculo[i] == null)
                break;
            else
                contador++;
        }
        this.vetVeiculo[contador] = veiculo;        
    }
```

[image: Digrama]

Comment: Coloque mais código relevante pra gente analisar. Precisamos saber direito a hierarquia, como stá declarado o `vetor`, onde será usado neste código. Não está muito claro o que deseja, o que quer dizer com "como faço pra inserir no vetor[] um objeto do tipo Carro, ou Moto, ou Barco, especificamente?". Um exemplo de como será inserido seria bom.

Comment: Bom dia bigown! Adicionei um modelo das classes pra facilitar o entendimento. De código, a unica coisa que fiz até agora foi a criação das classes, dos atributos, metodo construtor e getter e setter. Iria começar a fazer o metodo "insereVeiculo", porém já me deparei com a duvida de como inserir valores num vetor quando existe herança. No caso, quando o "usuario" for inserir um novo Carro, é necessario que use o getter e setter da classe Carro+Veiculo, o mesmo pra quando for uma Moto ou um Barco, entende?

Comment: Já ajudou, mas ainda não dá pra saber o que precisa, qual sua dificuldade. Na verdade eu nem estou vendo algum problema. Mas pode ser porque não tem contexto do que está fazendo. Um método jogado assim não indica muito pra gente poder ajudar.

Comment: Como estou aprendendo, ainda não tem nenhum problema pois eu não consegui começar a fazer. Minha primeira tarefa nesses sisteminha é criar um metodo para inserir no vetor veiculos do tipo Carro, Moto e Barco, preciso criar o código que faça essa inserção no vetor. Enquanto eu estava aprendendo, consegui criar um código que insere num vetor[] valores simples, exemplo, o usuario digita um numero e ele grava no vetor, agora, preciso criar o código, para inserir valores num vetor, porém não são valores tão simples, existe uma herança, e com isso o sistema deve usar os atributos da classe escolhida

Comment: Esse é o problema, você não tem um problema por isso não consegue nem explicar o que deseja. Me parece que seu código já faz o que deseja. Talvez não, mas não tenho como saber porque você se recusa fornecer informações que ajudam resolver o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a intenção é limitar pelo subtipo através de um objeto do supertipo, acredito que um simples verificação com `instanceof` já resolveria:

```
public void insereVeiculo(Veiculo veiculo)
{
        int contador = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.vetVeiculo.length; i++) 
        {
            if(this.vetVeiculo[i] == null)
                break;
            else
                contador++;
        }

        if(veiculo instanceof Carro) {   
            this.vetVeiculo[contador] = veiculo;        
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Se o que desejava era mesmo a resposta que foi aceita então o mais correto seria:

```
public void insere(Carro carro) {
    int contador = 0;
    for (carro : vetVeiculo) {
        if(caro == null) break;
        contador++;
    }
    vetVeiculo[contador] = carro;        
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/Polimorphism.cs).

Na verdade esse *loop* é horrível, mesmo eu tendo melhorado, e ineficiência é enorme. Como não sei o contexto nem posso ajudar mais.

Se ainda quiser fazer do jeito conceitualmente errado, pelo menos torne um pouco mais eficiente porque só varre quando é do tipo que deseja:

```
public void insereVeiculo(Veiculo veiculo) {
    if (veiculo instanceof Carro) {
        int contador = 0;
        for (carro : vetVeiculo) {
            if(caro == null) break;
            contador++;
        }
        this.vetVeiculo[contador] = veiculo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Você vai criar um vetor de Objetos.

```
Objects[] vetors = new Objects [] {Carro,Moto, Barco};
```

Dai no método de cada sub classe você implementa o `addVeiculo()` colocando o objeto no vetor.