# Como acedo aos getters e setters da sub classe?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Nesta aplicação nos temos a classe `Automóvel`:

```
public class Automovel {
    private String marca;
    private String matricula;
    private String anoConstrucao;
    private Motor motor;
    private int preco = 0;
```

Com os respectivos construtores, *getters* e *setters*.

E existe uma classe chamada `Motor` que é um atributo da classe `Automovel`.

Classe `Motor`:

```
private int potencia;

    public Motor() {}

    public Motor(int potencia){
        this.potencia = potencia;
    }

    public int getPotencia() {return this.potencia;}

    public void setPotencia(int potencia) {
        this.potencia = potencia
}
```

Existe também 2 subclasses desta classe (o `MotorEletrico` e o `MotorCombustão`):

```
public class MotorEletrico extends Motor {

    private int autonomia;
    public MotorEletrico() {}

    public MotorEletrico(int potencia, int autonomia) {
        super(potencia);
        this.autonomia = autonomia;
    }

    public int getAutonomia() {
        return autonomia;
    }

    public void setAutonomia(int autonomia) {
        this.autonomia = autonomia;
    }

}
```

E:

```
public class MotorCombustao extends Motor{

    private int cilindrada;
    private String combustivel;

    public MotorCombustao(){}

    public MotorCombustao(int potencia, int cilindrada, String combustivel){
        super(potencia);
        this.cilindrada = cilindrada;
        this.combustivel = combustivel;
    }

    public int getCilindrada(){
        return cilindrada;
    }

    public void setCilindrada(int cilindrada){
        this.cilindrada = cilindrada;
    }

    public String getCombustivel(){
        return combustivel;
    }

    public void setCombustivel(String combustivel){
        this.combustivel = combustivel;
    } 
}
```

Eu armazeno um automóvel com um motorX num *array* de objetos `Automovel`, mas quando eu vou tentar aceder aos *getters* e *setters* da sub classe (`MotorEletric`/`Combustao`), só aparecem os gets e os sets da classe mãe (`Motor`).

O meu problema é que eu não consigo aceder aos *getters* e *setters* das subclasses motor. Aqui esta um exemplo do que tentei:

```
        Automovel arrayteste[] = new Automovel[49];

        Motor motor1 = new MotorEletrico();
        motor1.setPotencia(5);

        Automovel automovel1 = new Automovel("Opel", "xx-12-xx", "2000", motor1, 2000);

        arrayteste[0] = automovel1;

        System.out.println(arrayteste[0].getMotor().getPotencia()); //Aqui, eu não consigo fazer o .getAutonomia
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 6):

Em essência não acessa, pelo menos não de forma direta e correta. Se você tem um campo ([atributo é o termo errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101)) ou métodos *getter/setter* exclusivos da sub classe ele só pode ser acessado em objetos tratados como seu tipo específico. Na sua classe `Automovel` você tem um campo tratado como objeto mais geral, então só deve acessar os membros que estão disponíveis nele.

O que está tentando fazer é uma [vazamento de abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101). Você é obrigado saber que os objetos ali tem herança e podem ser de determinados tipos. E mais, tem que saber quais tipos existem, então o motivo de fazer herança se perdeu (sim, a maioria das pessoas fazem herança e nem sabem porque, fazem porque viu outra fazendo). O uso da herança é justamente para não ter que saber quem são as classes filhas. As filhas sabem da mãe, mas não o oposto. Até tem técnica para isso, mas na maioria das vezes é errado, um dos motivos que é até "difícil" fazer.

Se quer mesmo fazer isso teria que verificar qual é o tipo real do objeto, fazer um *cast* para esse tipo e aí poderá chamar o método desejado porque agora ele é do tipo específico. Isso é conceitualmente errado. Se quer ver, eu já respondi como fazer em [Array list de classe pai com duas subclasses diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/391004/101).

Ainda pode ajudar: [Seguir o princípio OCP ou usar "instanceof"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/416658/101). E pra ver que o certo é outra forma, mas dá para fazer assim mesmo: [Como guardar valores num vetor usando herança/polimorfismo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/206847/101) (note que a resposta aceita não é a forma correta).

Pensa bem, não é nem regra da linguagem, se você sabe que método chamar então você sabe que método é esse. O que o compilador faz é apenas obrigar dizer que você sabe, até porque tem grande chance de estar fazendo errado. Sem um *cast* o tipo é `Motor` e não `MotorEletrico`. Em `Motor` não tem um método `getAutomnomia()`.

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente, de acordo com sua modelagem, isto não é possível sem usar um *cast* da classe `Motor` para `MotorEletrico`:

```
Motor motor = arrayteste[0].getMotor();
MotorEletrico motorEletrico = (MotorEletrico) motor;
```

A técnica acima é conhecida como ***downcasting***, que é o *cast* da classe pai (`Motor`) para uma classe filha (`MotorEletrico`).

Assim, finalmente, conseguirá acessar o método `getPotencia()`:

```
System.out.println(motorEletrico.getAutonomia());
```

Porém, dificilmente fará sentido fazer o *cast* direto sem antes verificar qual é a instância do `Motor`, pois caso a instância do `Motor` fosse `MotorCombustao` você receberia um erro. Para nossa sorte, isto pode ser verificado antes usando o operador `instanceof`.

O código final poderia ser então:

```
Motor motor = arrayteste[0].getMotor();

if (motor instanceof MotorEletrico) {
    MotorEletrico motorEletrico = (MotorEletrico) motor;
    System.out.println(motorEletrico.getAutonomia());
}
```